Does this family of density functions $f(x)=\frac{6\omega^2}{\pi^2}\frac{1}{x^3}\frac{1}{e^{\omega/x}-1}$ have a name?
While studying Planck's law, I derived a density function of the form
$$
f(x)=\frac{6\omega^2}{\pi^2}\frac{1}{x^3}\frac{1}{e^{\omega/x}-1},
$$
where $w,x>0$.  This density function has some relation to the Riemann $\zeta$ function as indicated by the normalizing constant. For example, the negative integer moments are related to $\zeta$ functions, i.e.,
$$
\mathsf E(X^{-n})=\frac{6}{\pi^2\omega^n}\Gamma(n+2)\zeta(n+2).
$$
My question is if anyone is aware of this density function being discussed in the literature and if it has a name.

The distribution
\begin{equation*}
g(y) = \frac{6}{\pi^2}\frac{y}{e^y - 1}
\end{equation*}
is one of the generalizations of the Planck distribution described by Johnson and Kotz.[1] If $Y$ is distributed as $g$, up to a factor your distribution describes $1/Y$, so I guess you might say it's an inverse generalized Planck distributed variable. Its mean is $12\zeta(3)/\pi^2$ and its second raw moment is $2\pi^2/5$.
[1] Johnson and Kotz, Distributions in Statistics: Continuous Univariate Distributions--2, 274, 1970.

Based on a clue from the reference provided by @Aruralreader we can use the geometric series formula to write the density of $X$ as
$$
f_X(x)=\frac{6\omega^2}{\pi^2}\frac{1}{x^3}\frac{1}{e^{\omega/x}-1}=
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\underbrace{\frac{n^{-2}}{\zeta(2)}}_{p_N(n)}\underbrace{\frac{(n\omega)^2}{\Gamma(2)}\frac{1}{x^{2+1}}e^{-n\omega/x}}_{f_{X|N}(x|n)}.
$$
Thus the distribution of $X$ has the hierarchical representation
$$
\begin{align}
X|N &\sim\operatorname{InverseGamma(2,N\omega)}\\
N &\sim\operatorname{Zeta}(2).
\end{align}
$$
In other words,
$$
X=\omega\frac{N}{G},
$$
where $N\sim\operatorname{Zeta}(2)$ and $G\sim\operatorname{Gamma}(2,1)$ are independent.
So while $X$ is an inverse Planck distribution, it can be represented as a scale family of the Zeta/Gamma ratio distribution.
